# Handlebars - Using handlebars clientside

Tags: javascript, gulp, handlebars.js

I've adopted a project with Handlebars and have run into an issue getting handlebars to render templates client side.

Basically the way it's setup at the moment is the templates are rendering out server side. I'm at a stage now where I need to be able to call handlebars in AJAX responses to reference handlebars templates using the following method:

```
<script id="ajax-comment" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <li>
    <p>{{{comment}}}</p>
  </li>
</script>
```

I understand how the method works but where i'm having trouble is actually getting the handlebars function to work on the client side in one of my javascript modules. Here is what i'm trying:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
console.log(Handlebars);
```

The error i'm getting whenever I try this is:

> Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ...\node_modules\handlebars\lib'

FS is obviously not available client side hence why it's not working but after reading through the various documentation on Handlebars around this, it seems to be the way you should do it. I'm not entirely sure why i'm getting this error, i'm not sure if this could be an issue with webpack. Handlebars is being called in via gulp-hb so not sure if this could also be the issue.

Any help as to why this could be happening would be much appreciated! Happy to provide any config files that could also help debug this.

Answer (score 1):

An example

```
 function onInitFs(fs) {
      console.log('Opened file system: ' + fs.name);
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024 /*5MB*/, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

You can try this using html5 fs api 
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/